# How to have tr border-bottom but not td

Tags: css

How to have tr border-bottom but not td (td without any border)?

I tried the following but td border 0 overrides the tr border too and just thead  and th get border!

```
table.admin_datagrid tbody tr {
     border:1px solid red;
}

table.admin_datagrid td{
    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Try using !important inside tr to make it override the td property.

Comment: `!important` is rarely, if ever, the way to go.

Comment: oh sorry I have beeing adding the jsfiddle but someone answered! :) Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did u mean border just between the rows and not between cols?

```
table.admin_datagrid tbody tr {

}

table.admin_datagrid td{
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-top:1px solid red;
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not that the `td` border overrides the `tr` border, the issue is that you're trying to set border on `tr`. Instead, try assigning a class on `td` elements in the row that need to have the bottom border:

HTML:

```
<table class="admin_datagrid">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="border-bottom">
            Text1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Text2
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table.admin_datagrid td.border-bottom {
     border-bottom: 1px solid red !important;
}

table.admin_datagrid td{
    border: 0;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J7b3M/

Answer (score 0):

Change order and add `display:block` :

```
table.admin_datagrid td{
    border: 0;
}

table.admin_datagrid tr {
     display: block;
     border:1px solid red;
}
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/z5GZN/

Answer (score 0):

Add [border-collapse:collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse) to your table:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j7eFa/1/)**

```
table{
      border-collapse: collapse; 
}
table.admin_datagrid tbody tr {
     border: 1px solid red;
}

table.admin_datagrid td{
    border: 0;
}
```